# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object(Python)

Tags: python, json, regex

I'm trying to count the numbers of components based on the json file I have below.

And here is what I have for now:

```
# counter for the numbers of components
def get_numbers_devices(e, name, locator, counter=0):
    if re.match(name, e.get(locator, None), re.I|re.M):
        counter += 1
    for child in e.get('children', []):
        counter = get_numbers_devices(child, name, locator, counter)
    return counter
```

For example:

```
num_memory = get_numbers_devices(data, 'bank:*', 'id')    # memory banks
print(num_memory)  # Output 2
```

However, when I try to use the below code to count how many disk I have, it gave me TypeError.

```
num_hdd = get_numbers_devices(data, '\/dev\/sda', 'logicalname')  # hdd Qty
print(num_hdd) # TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

It seems like an issue of my regex, but I have a little bit hard time to find out which part caused that issue.

Thank you all in advanced.

**json file:**
[dell.json](https://regex101.com/r/jitXRu/2)

Comment: `data` is probably `bytes` not `str`. BTW no need to escape slashes in your regex;

Comment: Don't parse json with regex.  Use the `json` module instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `data` is a dict, which I get from data = json.load(dell.json). I tried to remove escape slashes but it is still not working.

Comment: aside: `counter = get_numbers_devices(child, name, locator, counter)` should be `counter += get_numbers_devices(child, name, locator, counter)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your default value when not found is `None`, which is returned at some point and `re` module chokes on it.

You should return `""` as a default value when not found.

The other problem is that some of your keys are linked to lists (ex: `['/dev/sda1', '/media/ict/KINGSTON']`) so it's not working either.

So I cannot provide you with a running example, but with some code to check the data type so you get a proper error message when a non-string is found:

```
def get_numbers_devices(e, name, locator, counter=0):
    z = e.get(locator, "")
    if type(z) is not str:
        raise Exception("wrong value for {} key: {}".format(locator,z))
```

running that on your data I get:

```
Exception: wrong value for logicalname key: ['/dev/sda1', '/media/ict/KINGSTON']
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I still struggle on the function and hope I can twist my function a little bit.